# HapiJS Samesite config + Cloudflare (DNS)

Tags: cookies, dns, cloudflare, hapi.js

I am trying to setup 'samesite' config for my HapiJS. If I put it to 'Strict', only one of my domain (xxx.com) works.

For clarification, I am using NGINX docker image to host two webapps on two domain (xxx.com and yyy.com) on an OVH VPS.

I am also using Cloudflare and it seems that I don't have good DNS configuration on it.

Looks like I have to redirect my calls from yyy.com to xxx.com so HapiJS is going to accept my cookies.